# Flask not logging with logger provided by library?

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have the following code:

```
import logging
import pprint

from flask import Flask, request, url_for
from flask.ext.werobot import WeRoBot

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

robot = WeRoBot(token='banana', enable_session=False)
logger = logging.getLogger("WeRoBot")
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

@robot.handler
def reply(message):
  logger.error("TESTING")
  return "id:%s\ntarget:%s\nsource:%s\ncontent:%s" % (
    message.id, message.target, message.source, message.content)

robot.init_app(app, endpoint='werobot', rule='/wechat')

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return 'WeRoBot will handle at %s' % url_for('werobot')


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)
  app.logger.addHandler(logger)
  app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

And I am trying to use this logger provided by my library (https://github.com/binss/werobot-bin/blob/master/logger.py)

Right now all I am seeing is this in my flask console:

```
103.7.30.69 - - [22/May/2016 22:26:43] "POST /wechat?signature=147865ba8f78a860468dfb9276a1be6c1d735a06&timestamp=1463956003&nonce=784584663 HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Any ideas why the logger is not outputting anything?

### EDIT:

When I added `logger.error` in my code I am seeing this instead:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "WeRoBot"
103.7.30.69 - - [22/May/2016 22:33:48] "POST /wechat?signature=690728c359997933b6fe879a29b3e1a3f4bbd3a5&timestamp=1463956428&nonce=1767972375 HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Comment: Where are you logging anything-

Comment: @RobertMoskal Looks like my logger is missing.

Comment: Your logger is there. You can set the level. Does it work in other places?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually register your logger.  You need to instantiate your logger and then register it as a handler, something like:

```
robot = WeReBot(...)  # make my handler
logger = logging.getLogger()  # get a reference to the root logger
logger.addHandler(robot)  # register my handler
```

Here is the Python Docs Cookbook with more details: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging